# how to change default receiver image size on tv screen

Tags: ios, image, chromecast

I altered the sample code and set the value, and then found that the default receiver image size has no change on tv. how to change that?

```
GCKMediaMetadata *metadata = [[GCKMediaMetadata alloc] init];

  if (thumbnailURL) {
    [metadata addImage:[[GCKImage alloc] initWithURL:thumbnailURL width:200 height:100]]; //<=== alter here,  try to change "width:200 height:100" to "width:720 height:960", but there's no change.
  }

  GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation =
      [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:[url absoluteString]
                                          streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeNone
                                         contentType:mimeType
                                            metadata:metadata
                                      streamDuration:0
                                          customData:nil];
  [self.mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:autoPlay playPosition:startTime];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve; if you want the image to be differently sized on your TV, then yo have to make changes in your receiver, in the `<img/>` tag to adjust to the size that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customise the UI with a [default media receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default). Use the [styled media receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) instead  and specify the size of your image in the css.